# Inverse a sparse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization, sparse-matrices

I have a sparse singular matrix W where I want to find its inverse Q. My current method is to use $W*Q = I$ for an optimization process of approximating the convergence of cost function norm($I-W*Q$).

Within each iteration:

1. Compute the objective function value: norm($I-W*Q$)
2. Updating Q as the following: $Q = Q + stepSize*(W' * (I-W*Q))$
3. I applied a mask M that has the same size as Q so that the dot product $Q = Q.*M$ only keeps values in Q that has its corresponding position in M.
4. repeat iteration

The sparse matrix W has values of 1 for all of its elements.
The above method could not make cost function approximate to a small enough value and so when I check $Q$ with $W^-1$, they look quite different.

Is there a method that I can try to get a better result?

[Sparse Matrix Inverse with Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtE01.jpg)

Comment: It looks as though you suspect that $Q$ should have the same sparsity pattern as $W$. However, it is not generally true that the inverse of a sparse matrix is sparse, let alone that $Q$ should have the same sparsity pattern.

Comment: If you tell us more about your specific matrix, then we might be able to come up with tools that are applicable to your specific usage.

Comment: Also, if $W$ is singular, then what exactly do you mean by "find its inverse"?

Comment: Thank you! Q does not necessarily have to be sparse. For a sparse and singular W, we want to find the most approximate result of Q. So if we then inverse this Q, it should be very similar to W. For example, if I have a 10 X 10 random sparse matrix W, a 10 X 10 mask matrix M. M has element 1 at position (1,1), (1,2), (2,1),(2,2) as one cluster. The second cluster is at (3,3),(3,4),(4,3),(4,4), and so on. There are 5 clusters for a 10 X 10 matrix M. Within each iteration, Q is constrained by M.

Comment: @Moore462827 Perhaps it could be clarified: You want a matrix $Q$ whose *exact* inverse has the same sparsity pattern as $W$?

Comment: Sorry for confusion! Q needs to have the same sparsity pattern as M but not W. So W can be some matrix I got from experiment, and I can create a matrix M so that when I inverse W using above process, Q has to be masked by M. Please let me know if it still sounds confusing.

Comment: How is $M$ chosen and how does it relate to your choice of $W$?

Comment: The big environment is to inverse a connectome matrix $M$. So saying $W$ is 10 X 10 means there are 10 pre- and post-synaptic neurons. W is constructed by the connectivity of these neurons. $M$ is some simulation layout I want to constraint $Q$. The relation is that $Q^-1 = W$ and $Q$ has the same layout as $M$.

Comment: The example 5 clusters shown above is what I chose to inverse this W. For 10 X 10 matrix, I can also chose 2 clusters where first one has element 1 at position from row 1-5 and column 1-5. The second one has 1 at position from row 6-10 and column 6-10.

Comment: There is no direct relation between $W$ and $M$.

Comment: @Moore462827 Perhaps can you write out (edit your question) some good examples of $W,M$? So from what I can tell, you're trying to do Newton's method with matrix element constraints. This should work reasonably well, but only if you start from an initial good guess.

Comment: I added some pictures to the question so you can see it clearly. The first two rows are for 5 clusters and the last two rows are for 2 clusters. For a 10 by 10 matrix, sparse one has W and Q^-1 almost identical, and dense one does not have similar W and Q^-1 (this also happens if I extent matrix to by a 1000 by 1000 sparse matrix). I agree but worry about making a good guess as initial because the scale of the matrix can extent to be large later.

Comment: @Moore462827 In your picture for $M$, what are the green entries versus the blue ones?

Comment: The blue one is the elements in a cluster which contain all ones. The green one is some random connection between  two clusters. For simplicity, we are only keeping the adjacent clusters to be connected with each other.

Comment: @Moore462827 So $M(1,1) = 1$, and $M(1,4)$ is any real, nonzero number?

Comment: Yeah, all elements in M are 1 or 0.

Comment: @Moore462827 Then I'm confused. If $M(1,4)$ is either $0$ or $1$, why is it a different color than $M(1,1)$?

Comment: Sorry for make you confused! I just used a different color to notify that the 1 at that position has a different meaning from what are marked blue. So the blue region can stand for a cluster of neurons interact with each other in that cluster, and the green 1 shows that one or more neurons within one blue-colored cluster interact (for a connection) with a different cluster. Please let me know if this clarifies your confusion!

Comment: It seems like the problem you're trying to solve is the sparse approximate inverse problem: e.g. [these slides](https://www5.in.tum.de/lehre/vorlesungen/parnum/WS10/PARNUM_10.pdf).

Comment: @tch - thank you I will try and see how it goes!